# How can dataclasses be made to work better with __slots__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots, python-dataclasses

It [was decided](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/28) to remove direct support for `__slots__` from dataclasses for Python 3.7.

Despite this, `__slots__` can still be used with dataclasses:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C():
    __slots__ = "x"
    x: int
```

However, because of the way `__slots__` works it isn't possible to assign a default value to a dataclass field:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C():
    __slots__ = "x"
    x: int = 1
```

This results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'x' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

How can `__slots__` and default `dataclass` fields be made to work together?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

2021 UPDATE: direct support for `__slots__` is [added to python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69661861/758345). I am leaving this answer for posterity and won't be updating it.

The problem is not unique to dataclasses. ANY conflicting class attribute will stomp all over a slot:

```
>>> class Failure:
...     __slots__ = tuple("xyz")
...     x=1
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'x' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable
```

This is simply how slots work. The error happens because `__slots__` creates a class-level descriptor object for each slot name:

```
>>> class Success:
...     __slots__ = tuple("xyz")
...
>>>
>>> type(Success.x)
<class 'member_descriptor'>
```

In order to prevent this conflicting variable name error, the class namespace must be altered *before* the class object is instantiated such that there are not two objects competing for the same member name in the class:

- the specified (default) value*
- the slot descriptor (created by the slots machinery)

For this reason, an `__init_subclass__` method on a parent class will not be sufficient, nor will a class decorator, because in both cases the class object has already been created by the time these functions have received the class to alter it.

### Current option: write a metaclass

Until such time as the slots machinery is altered to allow more flexibility,  or the language itself provides an opportunity to alter the class namespace before the class object is instantiated, our only choice is to use a metaclass.

Any metaclass written to solve this problem must, at minimum:

- remove the conflicting class attributes/members from the namespace
- instantiate the class object to create the slot descriptors
- save references to the slot descriptors
- put the previously removed members and their values back in the class `__dict__` (so the `dataclass` machinery can find them)
- pass the class object to the `dataclass` decorator
- restore the slots descriptors to their respective places
- also take into account plenty of corner cases (such as what to do if there is a `__dict__` slot)

To say the least, this is an extremely complicated endeavor. It would be easier to define the class like the following- without a default value so that the conflict doesn't occur at all- and then add a default value afterward.

### Current option: make alterations after class object instantiation

The unaltered dataclass would look like this:

```
@dataclass
class C:
    __slots__ = "x"
    x: int
```

The alteration is straightforward. Change the `__init__` signature to reflect the desired default value, and then change the `__dataclass_fields__` to reflect the presence of a default value.

```
from functools import wraps

def change_init_signature(init):
    @wraps(init)
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        init(self,x)
    return __init__

C.__init__ = change_init_signature(C.__init__)

C.__dataclass_fields__["x"].default = 1
```

Test:

```
>>> C()
C(x=1)
>>> C(2)
C(x=2)
>>> C.x
<member 'x' of 'C' objects>
>>> vars(C())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

It works!

### Current option: a `setmember` decorator

With some effort, a so-called `setmember` decorator could be employed to automatically alter the class in the manner above. This would require deviating from the dataclasses API in order to define the default value in a location other than inside the class body, perhaps something like:

```
@setmember(x=field(default=1))
@dataclass
class C:
    __slots__="x"
    x: int
```

The same thing could also be accomplished through a `__init_subclass__` method on a parent class:

```
class SlottedDataclass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.__init_subclass__()
        # make the class changes here

class C(SlottedDataclass, x=field(default=1)):
    __slots__ = "x"
    x: int
```

### Future possibility: change the slots machinery

Another possibility, as mentioned above, would be for the python language to alter the slots machinery to allow more flexibility. One way of doing this might be to change the slots descriptor itself to store class level data at the time of class definition.

This could be done, perhaps, by supplying a `dict` as the `__slots__` argument (see below). The class-level data (1 for x, 2 for y) could just be stored on the descriptor itself for retrieval later:

```
class C:
    __slots__ = {"x": 1, "y": 2}

assert C.x.value == 1
assert C.y.value == y
```

One difficulty: it may be desired to only have a `slot_member.value` present on some slots and not others. This could be accommodated by importing a null-slot factory from a new `slottools` library:

```
from slottools import nullslot

class C:
    __slots__ = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": nullslot()}

assert not hasattr(C.z, "value")
```

The style of code suggested above would be a deviation from the dataclasses API. However, the slots machinery itself could even be altered to allow for this style of code, with accommodation of the dataclasses API specifically in mind:

```
class C:
    __slots__ = "x", "y", "z"
    x = 1  # 1 is stored on C.x.value
    y = 2  # 2 is stored on C.y.value

assert C.x.value == 1
assert C.y.value == y
assert not hasattr(C.z, "value")
```

### Future possibility: "prepare" the class namespace inside the class body

The other possibility is altering/preparing (synonymous with the `__prepare__` method of a metaclass) the class namespace.

Currently, there is no opportunity (other than writing a metaclass) to write code that alters the class namespace before the class object is instantiated, and the slots machinery goes to work. This could be changed by creating a hook for preparing the class namespace beforehand, and making it so that an error complaining about the conflicting names is only produced after that hook has been run.

This so-called `__prepare_slots__` hook could look something like this, which I think is not too bad:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, prepare_slots

@dataclass
class C:
    __slots__ = ('x',)
    __prepare_slots__ = prepare_slots
    x: int = field(default=1)
```

The `dataclasses.prepare_slots` function would simply be a function-- similar to the [`__prepare__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace)-- that receives the class namespace and alters it before the class is created. For this case in particular, the default dataclass field values would be stored in some other convenient place so that they can be retrieved after the slot descriptor objects have been created.

---

* Note that the default field value conflicting with the slot might also be created by the dataclass machinery if `dataclasses.field` is being used.

Comment: When you define both a slot and a default for an attribute, you're not actually *using* the slot; you remove the generated slot descriptor to replace it with the default value, so instances have space allocated for a slot that cannot be accessed.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think that's right- the slot still can be accessed, it just can't be changed after the descriptor is removed. It is read-only at that point: `C.slot=1`, `print(C().slot)` works fine. Even `C.slot`, then `C.slot=1`, `print(C().slot)` works.

Comment: That's not accessing the slot. That's accessing the class variable you replaced the slot descriptor with.

Comment: @user2357112 I see. You're right. But in actual usage it certainly appears as if the slot is being used- but you are correct, answer needs editing.

Comment: @user2357112 Interesting: even if the slot is truly *gone*, you are still prevented  adding the slot to the instance: `del C.slot`, `C.slot=1`, `C().slot=2` <- ERROR -- there's not a lot of practical difference between this result and my incorrect interpretation of what was happening

Comment: I believe that currently, to get both the default value and the slot to work correctly, your metaclass would have to perform a very delicate shuffle: remove the defaults, call `super().__new__`, replace the defaults (while saving the slot descriptors), call `dataclass`, and finally replace the slot descriptors. This seems very fragile and bug-prone.

Comment: @user2357112 perhaps. the dataclasses module seems to be taking care of the last stop on its own just fine.

Comment: @user2357112 not that it is replacing the descriptors, but it doesn't need to; dataclasses works with descriptors already. nothing special is needed.

Comment: That's not right. With your `C1`, it uses the `__dict__` instead of the slots, because it can't find the slots (except for `x`). With `C2`, there is no `__dict__`, so it can't handle instance attribute assignment at all.

Comment: @user2357112 I see- yup, `z` should not be in instance dict in `C1`. so as you said: the dataclass defaults need to be replaced with the slots descriptors. hmmm.

Comment: @user2357112 Updated with a much simpler approach.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and created `slotted_dataclass` descriptor, but since the code would be too long for a comment, I did it in a new answer — I hope that's OK with you.

Comment: Where does your `@setmembers` come from? Couldn't find it.

Comment: @buhtz I referred to it as a "a so-called `setmember` decorator". you'd have to write it yourself. I just describe what such a decorator would do in the answer.

Answer (score 51):

In Python 3.10+ you can use `slots=True` with a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) to make it more memory-efficient:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Point:
    x: int = 0
    y: int = 0
```

This way you can set default field values as well.

Comment: Why not just using `__slots__` directly?

Answer (score 10):

As noted already in the answers, data classes from dataclasses cannot generate slots for the simple reason that slots must be defined before a class is created.

In fact, the [PEP for data classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#support-for-automatically-setting-slots) explicitly mentions this:

> At least for the initial release, `__slots__` will not be supported. `__slots__` needs to be added at class creation time. The Data Class decorator is called after the class is created, so in order to add `__slots__` the decorator would have to create a new class, set `__slots__`, and return it. Because this behavior is somewhat surprising, the initial version of Data Classes will not support automatically setting `__slots__`.

I wanted to use slots because I needed to initialise many, many data class instances in another project. I ended up writing my own own alternative implementation of data classes which supports this, among a few extra features: [**dataclassy**](https://github.com/biqqles/dataclassy).

dataclassy uses a metaclass approach which has numerous advantages - it enables decorator inheritance, considerably reduced code complexity and of course, the generation of slots. With dataclassy the following is possible:

```
from dataclassy import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Pet:
    name: str
    age: int
    species: str
    fluffy: bool = True
```

Printing `Pet.__slots__` outputs the expected `{'name', 'age', 'species', 'fluffy'}`, instances have no `__dict__` attribute and the overall memory footprint of the object is therefore lower. These observations indicate that `__slots__` has been successfully generated and is effective. Plus, as evidenced, default values work just fine.

Comment: Note that, as others have mentioned, this is not true anymore

Answer (score 6):

The least involved solution I've found for this problem is to specify a custom `__init__` using `object.__setattr__` to assign values.

```
@dataclass(init=False, frozen=True)
class MyDataClass(object):
    __slots__ = (
        "required",
        "defaulted",
    )
    required: object
    defaulted: Optional[object]

    def __init__(
        self,
        required: object,
        defaulted: Optional[object] = None,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        object.__setattr__(self, "required", required)
        object.__setattr__(self, "defaulted", defaulted)
```

Comment: Such a bummer that the easiest method requires writing the init yourself, this defeating one if the biggest wins dataclasses brings to the table!

Comment: Yes, I'd definitely agree.  Beyond that, you're specifying the attribute names as strings which are easily missed by ide's.  All the existing solutions I've seem ugly/error prone in some way...

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to generate the slots parameter inside the class body, from the typed annotations.
this can look like:

```py
@dataclass
class Client:
    first: str
    last: str
    age_of_signup: int
    
     __slots__ = slots(__annotations__)
```

where the `slots` function is:

```py
def slots(anotes: Dict[str, object]) -> FrozenSet[str]:
    return frozenset(anotes.keys())
```

running that would generate a **slots** parameter that looks like:
`frozenset({'first', 'last', 'age_of_signup})`

This takes the annotations above it and makes a set of the specified names. The limitation here is you must re-type the `__slots__ = slots(__annotations__)` line for every class and it must be positioned below all the annotations and it does not work for annotations with default arguments.
This also has the advantage that the slots parameter will never conflict with the specified annotations so you can feel free to add or remove members and not worry about maintaining sperate lists.

Comment: Huh. Who knew that putting slots after the class members would make such a difference.  I'll have to try this later.

Comment: However it's still broken if you assign anything to the slot using the dataclasses API.

Comment: But why convert it to `frozenset` instead of just using `__annotations__.keys()`?

Answer (score 4):

Following [Rick Teachey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437514/rick-teachey)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50180784/), I created a `slotted_dataclass` decorator. It can take, in keyword arguments, anything that you would specify after `[field]: [type] =` in a dataclass without `__slots__` — both default values for fields and `field(...)`. Specifying arguments that should go to old `@dataclass` constructor is also possible, but in dictionary object as a first positional argument. So this:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Test:
    a: dict = field(repr=False)
    b: int = 42
    c: list = field(default_factory=list)
```

would become:

```
@slotted_dataclass({'frozen': True}, a=field(repr=False), b=42, c=field(default_factory=list))
class Test:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    a: dict
    b: int
    c: list
```

And here is the source code of this new decorator:

```
def slotted_dataclass(dataclass_arguments=None, **kwargs):
    if dataclass_arguments is None:
        dataclass_arguments = {}

    def decorator(cls):
        old_attrs = {}

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            old_attrs[key] = getattr(cls, key)
            setattr(cls, key, value)

        cls = dataclass(cls, **dataclass_arguments)
        for key, value in old_attrs.items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)
        return cls

    return decorator
```

### Code explanation

The code above takes advantage of the fact that `dataclasses` module gets default field values by calling `getattr` on the class. That makes it possible to deliver our default values by replacing appropriate fields in the `__dict__` of the class (which is done in the code by using `setattr` function). The class generated by the `@dataclass` decorator will be then completely identical to the class generated by specifying those after `=`, like we would if the class didn't contain `__slots__`.

But since the `__dict__` of the class with `__slots__` contains `member_descriptor` objects:

```
>>> class C:
...     __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'c')
...
>>> C.__dict__['a']
<member 'a' of 'C' objects>
>>> type(C.__dict__['a'])
<class 'member_descriptor'>
```

a nice thing to do is backup those objects and restore them after `@dataclass` decorator does its job, which is done in the code by using `old_attrs` dictionary.

Comment: the real bummer here of course is it deviates from the dataclasses API, but the very nice API is a big part of the reason why i like dataclasses so much in the first place.

Comment: Why is it wrong to "deviate from the dataclasses API" in this case, in your opinion?

Comment: It's not wrong necessarily, it's just that the API is very nice to use. Also, here's an `add_slots` utility function for people who want to do this: [`add_slots`](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/blob/d4c87c663feb0617fd8c7e6fe0a58882c4ccd468/dataclass_tools.py)