# Dataclass to dict when using slots

Tags: python, dictionary, slots

If I use a regular dataclass I can get a dict with

```
@dataclass
class Cat:
   fur: bool
   meow: int

Cat(True, 3).__dict__
```

But it doesn't work when using `__slots__`. What is the most efficient solution to use instead?

```
@dataclass
class Cat:
   __slots___ = ['fur', 'meow']
   fur: bool
   meow: int

# Doesn't work:
Cat(True, 3).__dict__
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can dataclasses be made to work better with \_\_slots\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180735/how-can-dataclasses-be-made-to-work-better-with-slots)

Comment: No. I'm trying to make a dictionary/json string from the dataclass with __slots__

Comment: Why not just create a method to do it `return {'fur'self.fur, 'meow': self meow}`

Comment: Also note, `__dict__`  doesn't create a dict, it *is the actual namespace of the instance*

Comment: Note, there is the `dataclasses.asdict` function already in the module

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code--I believe it should work as written. Can you paste the error message you are seeing?

Comment: You're right, it somehow does work...
It's strange that I had an error message when I first tried it, but I was wrong, you can use __dict__ even if the dataclass has slots and it works. We should close this question

Answer (score 1):

> But it doesn't work when using `__slots__`. What is the most efficient solution to use instead?

Assuming the goal as listed above, I would personally advise against `dataclasses.asdict()`, as specific sections of the code might slow down processing of dataclass field values. For instance, it [calls `copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) on any complex types that it encounters (such as `datetime`) which as I understand, might not be desirable behavior; it is also rather inefficient to do this, as I demonstrate below.

In any case, here is the simplest (and most ***efficient***) approach to resolve it.

The first step would be to create a helper Mixin class, named as `SerializableMixin` or anything else. This would then access a class's `__slots__` namespace, and generate the `dict()` and `json()` methods specifically for the given subclass. Note that this approach extends from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903586/10237506).

Assuming your class is relatively simple, and *doesn't* contain any complex types or nested dataclasses:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import json
from typing import Any


class SerializableMixin:
    """
    Mixin class to add a `dict()` and `json()` method on classes that define
    a __slots__ attribute.
    """

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls_slots = getattr(cls, '__slots__', None)

        # only if/when slots have been declared on the class
        if not cls_slots:
            return

        body_lines = ','.join(f"'{f}':self.{f}" for f in cls_slots)
        # Compute the text of the entire function(s).
        txt = (f'def dict(self):\n'
               f' return {{{body_lines}}}\n'
               f'def json(self):\n'
               f' return dumps({{{body_lines}}})')

        ns = {}
        fn_locals = {'dumps': json.dumps}
        exec(txt, fn_locals, ns)

        cls.dict = ns['dict']
        cls.json = ns['json']

    # added for IDE auto-completion purposes
    def dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]: ...
    def json(self) -> str: ...
```

To handle more complex types such as `datetime`, and nested dataclasses:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import json

from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any
from uuid import UUID


_defaults = {UUID: str,
             datetime: datetime.isoformat}


def _default_fn(o: Any):  # `default` argument to `json.dumps`
    _dict = getattr(o, 'dict', None)
    return _dict() if _dict else _defaults.get(type(o), str)(o)


class SerializableMixin:
    """
    Mixin class to add a `dict()` and `json()` method on classes that define
    a __slots__ attribute.
    """

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls_slots = getattr(cls, '__slots__', None)

        # only if/when slots have been declared on the class
        if not cls_slots:
            return

        body_lines = ','.join(f"'{f}':self.{f}" for f in cls_slots)
        # Compute the text of the entire function(s).
        txt = (f'def dict(self):\n'
               f' return {{{body_lines}}}\n'
               f'def json(self):\n'
               f' return dumps({{{body_lines}}}, default=default)')

        ns = {}
        fn_locals = {'dumps': json.dumps, 'default': _default_fn}
        exec(txt, fn_locals, ns)

        cls.dict = ns['dict']
        cls.json = ns['json']

    # added for IDE auto-completion purposes
    def dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]: ...
    def json(self) -> str: ...
```

In any case, usage would be as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Cat(SerializableMixin):
    fur: bool
    meow: int


kitty = Cat(True, 3)

print(kitty.dict())
print(kitty.json())
```

Output:

```
{'fur': True, 'meow': 3}
{"fur": true, "meow": 3}
```

---

To prove that this is indeed more efficient, I use the `timeit` module to compare against a similar approach with `dataclasses.asdict`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import json
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Any
from uuid import UUID, uuid4


_defaults = {UUID: str,
             datetime: datetime.isoformat}


def _default_fn(o: Any):  # `default` argument to `json.dumps`
    _dict = getattr(o, 'dict', None)
    return _dict() if _dict else _defaults.get(type(o), str)(o)


class SerializableMixin:
    """
    Mixin class to add a `dict()` and `json()` method on classes that define
    a __slots__ attribute.
    """

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        # only if/when slots have been declared on the class
        if hasattr(cls, '__slots__'):
            cls._generate_helper_methods()

    @classmethod
    def _generate_helper_methods(cls):
        body_lines = ','.join(f"'{f}':self.{f}" for f in cls.__slots__)
        # Compute the text of the entire function(s).
        txt = (f'def dict(self):\n'
               f' return {{{body_lines}}}\n'
               f'def json(self):\n'
               f' return dumps({{{body_lines}}}, default=default)')

        ns = {}
        fn_locals = {'dumps': json.dumps, 'default': _default_fn}
        exec(txt, fn_locals, ns)

        cls.dict = ns['dict']
        cls.json = ns['json']

    # added for IDE auto-completion purposes
    def dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]: ...
    def json(self) -> str: ...


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Inner(SerializableMixin):
    # for Python version < 3.10, remove `slots=True` above and uncomment the below
    # __slots__ = ('string', )
    string: str = 'hello world'


@dataclass(slots=True)
class Cat(SerializableMixin):
    # for Python version < 3.10, remove `slots=True` above and uncomment the below
    # __slots___ = ('fur', 'meow', 'id', 'dt', 'inner')
    fur: bool
    meow: int
    id: UUID = field(default_factory=uuid4)
    dt: datetime = datetime.min
    inner: Inner = field(default_factory=Inner)


@dataclass
class Cat2:
    __slots___ = ('fur', 'meow', 'id', 'dt', 'inner')
    fur: bool
    meow: int
    id: UUID = field(default_factory=uuid4)
    dt: datetime = datetime.min
    inner: Inner = field(default_factory=Inner)

    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(asdict(self).items())

    # this approach is faster, since `asdict` already calls `copy.deepcopy()` for us
    as_dict_alt = asdict

    def as_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.as_dict(), default=_default_fn)


_id = uuid4()

kitty = Cat(True, 3, id=_id)
kitty2 = Cat2(True, 3, id=_id)

print('dict:            ', timeit('kitty.dict()', globals=globals()))
print('asdict:          ', timeit('kitty2.as_dict()', globals=globals()))
print('asdict (alt):    ', timeit('kitty2.as_dict_alt()', globals=globals()))
print('dict -> json:    ', timeit('kitty.json()', globals=globals()))
print('asdict -> json:  ', timeit('kitty2.as_json()', globals=globals()))

# `kitty.dict()` is not equal because `inner` value is still an `Inner` object
assert kitty.dict() != kitty2.as_dict() == kitty2.as_dict_alt()
# `json()` string values should be equal
assert kitty.json() == kitty2.as_json()

print()
print('dict:\n ', kitty.dict())
print('json:\n ', kitty.json())
```

Results for Python 3.10, on Mac M1:

```
dict:             0.1584392080003454
asdict:           8.291836708000119
asdict (alt):     8.119467332999193
dict -> json:     3.4996820830001525
asdict -> json:   12.136880125000971
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.10 here

I agree with [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga). `__dict__` is the actual namespace of the instance and you can use `dataclasses.asdict()` to create a dict and JSON string.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class Cat:
    __slots___ = ('fur', 'meow')
    fur: bool
    meow: int

    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(asdict(self).items())

    def as_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.as_dict())


kitty = Cat(True, 3)
print(kitty.as_dict())
print(kitty.as_json())
```

inspired and referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604922/how-to-convert-python-dataclass-to-dictionary-of-string-literal#:%7E:text=8-,You%20can,-use%20dataclasses.asdict).