# How to convert Python dataclass to dictionary of string literal?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-dataclasses

Given a dataclass like below:

```
class MessageHeader(BaseModel):
    message_id: uuid.UUID

    def dict(self, **kwargs):
        return json.loads(self.json())
```

I would like to get a dictionary of string literal when I call `dict` on `MessageHeader`
The desired outcome of dictionary is like below:

```
{'message_id': '383b0bfc-743e-4738-8361-27e6a0753b5a'}
```

I want to avoid using 3rd party library like `pydantic` & I do not want to use `json.loads(self.json())` as there are extra round trips

Is there any better way to convert a dataclass to a dictionary with string literal like above?

Comment: Is  `uuid.UUID` already a string or some other type?

Comment: When I call `dict` from `pydantic`, it returns `uuid.UUID` as it is. I need the `UUID` as a string in dictionary

Comment: If you don't wanna use 3rd party libraries or even builtins, you probably came to Python from Assembler

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use [`dataclasses.asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

class MessageHeader(BaseModel):
    message_id: uuid.UUID

    def dict(self):
        return {k: str(v) for k, v in asdict(self).items()}
```

If you're sure that your class only has string values, you can skip the dictionary comprehension entirely:

```
class MessageHeader(BaseModel):
    message_id: uuid.UUID

    dict = asdict
```

Comment: Note that `asdict` only returns keys that are defined at init

Comment: @crypdick. That's an important note indeed

Answer (score 16):

For absolute ***pure, unadulterated speed*** and ***boundless efficiency***,  the kinds of which could even cause the likes of Chuck Norris to take pause and helplessly look on in awe, I humbly recommend this *remarkably well planned-out* approach with `__dict__`:

```py
def dict(self):
    _dict = self.__dict__.copy()
    _dict['message_id'] = str(_dict['message_id'])
    return _dict
```

For a class that defines a **`__slots__` attribute**, such as with `@dataclass(slots=True)`, the above approach most likely won't work, as the `__dict__` attribute won't be available on class  instances. In that case, a *highly efficient* "shoot for the moon" approach such as below could instead be viable:

```py
def dict(self):
    body_lines = ','.join(f"'{f}':" + (f'str(self.{f})' if f == 'message_id'
                                       else f'self.{f}') for f in self.__slots__)
    # Compute the text of the entire function.
    txt = f'def dict(self):\n return {{{body_lines}}}'
    ns = {}
    exec(txt, locals(), ns)
    _dict_fn = self.__class__.dict = ns['dict']
    return _dict_fn(self)
```

In case anyone's teetering at the edge of their seats right now (I *know*, this is really incredible, *breakthrough*-level stuff) - I've added my personal timings via the `timeit` module below, that should hopefully shed a little more light in the performance aspect of things.

FYI, the approaches with pure `__dict__` are inevitably *much* faster than `dataclasses.asdict()`.

> Note: Even though `__dict__` works better in this particular case, `dataclasses.asdict()` will likely be better for composite dictionaries, such as ones with nested dataclasses, or values with mutable types such as `dict` or `list`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
from uuid import UUID, uuid4


class DictMixin:
    """Mixin class to add a `dict()` method on classes that define a __slots__ attribute"""

    def dict(self):
        body_lines = ','.join(f"'{f}':" + (f'str(self.{f})' if f == 'message_id'
                                           else f'self.{f}') for f in self.__slots__)
        # Compute the text of the entire function.
        txt = f'def dict(self):\n return {{{body_lines}}}'
        ns = {}
        exec(txt, locals(), ns)
        _dict_fn = self.__class__.dict = ns['dict']
        return _dict_fn(self)


@dataclass
class MessageHeader:
    message_id: UUID = field(default_factory=uuid4)
    string: str = 'a string'
    integer: int = 1000
    floating: float = 1.0

    def dict1(self):
        _dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        _dict['message_id'] = str(_dict['message_id'])
        return _dict

    def dict2(self):
        return {k: str(v) if k == 'message_id' else v
                for k, v in self.__dict__.items()}

    def dict3(self):
        return {k: str(v) if k == 'message_id' else v
                for k, v in asdict(self).items()}


@dataclass(slots=True)
class MessageHeaderWithSlots(DictMixin):
    message_id: UUID = field(default_factory=uuid4)
    string: str = 'a string'
    integer: int = 1000
    floating: float = 1.0

    def dict2(self):
        return {k: str(v) if k == 'message_id' else v
                for k, v in asdict(self).items()}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import timeit

    header = MessageHeader()
    header_with_slots = MessageHeaderWithSlots()

    n = 10000
    print('dict1():  ', timeit('header.dict1()', number=n, globals=globals()))
    print('dict2():  ', timeit('header.dict2()', number=n, globals=globals()))
    print('dict3():  ', timeit('header.dict3()', number=n, globals=globals()))

    print('slots -> dict():  ', timeit('header_with_slots.dict()', number=n, globals=globals()))
    print('slots -> dict2(): ', timeit('header_with_slots.dict2()', number=n, globals=globals()))

    print()

    dict__ = header.dict1()
    print(dict__)

    asdict__ = header.dict3()
    print(asdict__)

    assert isinstance(dict__['message_id'], str)
    assert isinstance(dict__['integer'], int)

    assert header.dict1() == header.dict2() == header.dict3()
    assert header_with_slots.dict() == header_with_slots.dict2()
```

Results on my Mac M1 laptop:

```
dict1():   0.005992999998852611
dict2():   0.00800508284009993
dict3():   0.07069579092785716
slots -> dict():   0.00583599996753037
slots -> dict2():  0.07395245810039341

{'message_id': 'b4e17ef9-1a58-4007-9cef-39158b094da2', 'string': 'a string', 'integer': 1000, 'floating': 1.0}
{'message_id': 'b4e17ef9-1a58-4007-9cef-39158b094da2', 'string': 'a string', 'integer': 1000, 'floating': 1.0}
```

---

*Note:* For a more "complete" implementation of `DictMixin` (named as `SerializableMixin`), check out [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237566/10237506) I had also added.

Comment: Any idea what `asdict` is doing to slow it down so much?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm not *entirely* sure, but my money's on the `copy.deepcopy()` call. If you look at the dataclasses source code for `asdict`, you can see it calls `deepcopy` on any complex or unknown type, which in this case would likely be the `UUID` object.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You may add a note that while it works better in this case, asdict will likely be better for composite dictionaries.

Comment: @RyanDeschamps done. agreed that was something that should be mentioned at least.

Comment: This won't work with the slots=True dataclass parameter introduced in python 3.10

Comment: @G.Ghez good point. I've also updated my answer with a version that works for the `slots=True` approach, as mentioned.

Comment: Your code is vulnerability prone by calling python builtin `exec()`

Comment: @Alex-Bogdanov Thanks, I didn’t know that. How can I fix it? I’m not sure of an alternative to dynamically generate a function in Python, but open to suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

This is a top google result for "dataclass to dict", and the answers above are overly complicated. You're probably looking for this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class MessageHeader():
    uuid: str = "abcd"
vars(MessageHeader()) # or MessageHeader().__dict__
```

Comment: What about `slots=True`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@rv.kvetch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903586/13438431), I wrote this decorator, which will generate the code for an `asdict` method on the fly based on the class definition. It also supports subclassing, meaning the subclass will inherit superclass' attributes.

Decorator:

```
import typing


def generate_dict_method(
        __source: typing.Literal["slots", "annotations"],
        __name: str,
        /,
        **custom_mappings: typing.Callable[[typing.Any], typing.Any]
):
    if custom_mappings is None:
        custom_mappings = dict()

    def decorator(cls):
        attributes = set()
        for mc in cls.__mro__:
            if __source == 'annotations':
                attrs = getattr(mc, "__annotations__", None)
                if attrs:
                    attrs = attrs.keys()
            elif __source == "slots":
                attrs = getattr(mc, "__slots__", None)
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError(__source)
            if attrs:
                attributes.update(attrs)

        if not attributes:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Unable to generate `{__name}` method for `{cls.__qualname__}` class: "
                "no attributes found."
            )

        funclocals = {}
        mapping_to_funcname = {}

        for attrname, f in custom_mappings.items():
            funcname = f'__parse_{attrname}'
            funclocals[funcname] = f
            mapping_to_funcname[attrname] = funcname

        body_lines = ','.join([
            f'"{attrname}": ' + (f'self.{attrname}' if attrname not in custom_mappings
                                 else f'{mapping_to_funcname[attrname]}(self.{attrname})')
            for attrname in attributes
        ])
        txt = f'def {__name}(self):\n return {{{body_lines}}}'
        d = dict()
        exec(txt, funclocals, d)
        setattr(cls, __name, d[__name])
        return cls

    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json


@dataclass(slots=True, kw_only=True)
class TestBase:
    i1: int
    i2: int


@generate_dict_method("annotations", "asdict", d=(lambda x: "FUNNY" + json.dumps(x) + "JSON"))
@dataclass(slots=True, kw_only=True)
class Test(TestBase):
    i: int
    b: bool
    s: str
    d: dict


a = Test(i=1, b=True, s="test", d={"test": "test"}, i1=2, i2=3)
print(a.asdict())
```

Output:

```
{'d': 'FUNNY{"test": "test"}JSON', 'i': 1, 'i1': 2, 'b': True, 's': 'test', 'i2': 3}
```

As you can see, you only need to provide a custom parser for the `**custom_mappings` argument with the name of your attribute. This way you can mutate the attribute in any way you see fit.

In your case you can provide the `str` function for the `message_id` attribute.